# How to restart Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge Setup Wizard

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge, setup-wizard

How to restart the Samsung S7 edge setup wizard without factory reset like the one when it's first turned on.

Comment: The setup wizard is for setting up device for first use, so i do know why you would want to start it again. Although I think it could be possible by ADB Shell commands. You have to know the package name though.

Comment: Can you advise me with a command please.

Comment: try the am command: `am start -n package_name`